# IMAP protocol "unknown error(10057)"

Tags: php, email, ssl, wamp, imap

i'm having a big trouble with the IMAP protocol in PHP.

I tried so many different ways to gather emails from an Gmail account but nothing works for me.

I'm using a WampServer 3.1.0 localhost with every version of every services up to date (except PHP, i'm not using 7.1.9 but the 7.0.23 one)

Here is the code for a Gmail attempt :

```
<?php
    $hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}'; 
    $username = 'myemail@gmail.com'; $password = 'mypassword'; 
    $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

    print_r(imap_errors());
?>
```

Here are the errors :

> Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream
> {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert} in
> C:\wamp64\www\Projet_entreprise\imap_03bis_list.php on line 4
>
> Notice: Unknown: Can't connect to gmail-imap.l.google.com,993: Unknown error (10057) (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Notice: Unknown: Can't connect to gmail-imap.l.google.com,993: Unknown error (10057) (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0

(My password is only numbers so i tried with and without quotes, same issue).

Even if I activated the IMAP Protocol in the Gmail account settings and the PHP extensions "php_imap" and "php_openssl" are enabled (green validate icon), same issue.

I'd really be grateful if you could try to help me ...

Thank you all for reading and have a good day.

Comment: Your host is not reachable. Try writing that to browser.

Comment: try to diagnose connection problems by running `openssl s_client -connect gmail-imap.l.google.com:993`. You can grab copy of OpenSSL for your OS [here](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries)

Comment: the problem is that i'm using a company PC and i can't install or downloads things like this. is there a way to check if a port is not blocked by my company's firewall except telnet ? (telnet is marked as unsecured, so it's forbidden to use it ...)

Comment: and for Justinas, thank you for your advice, even thought it's the first thing I did, but even after looking for 3 pages of Google's search, nobody brings a concrete solution ..

Comment: The concrete solution is you need to find out if you're firewalled.  All signs point that you are.